# My own Java compiler & bytecode: Problems invoking functions

Tags: java, compiler-construction, bytecode

I'm writing a compiler in Java for Java with the JVM as target machine and i'm trying to get function calls working. But when i try to run the class file created by my compiler, i'm getting this error: 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Test, method: test signature: (I)I) Wrong return type in function".

Here the sample code:

```
 public class Test
 {
     public static int test(int a)
     {
        return a;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        int b;
        b = test(b);    
     }
  }
```

the created class file itself:

[Test.class](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B44tWhZvAXJsMWtDSE9QX2dpLVE/edit?usp=sharing)

(if you try to download it, Google says that it contains a virus. So i provided a pic

of the created class file:

[Classfile & javap](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B44tWhZvAXJsbjhxdW9EVTd1UE0/edit?usp=sharing)

I've no idea whats wrong with that class file.

Comment: I have not the slightest idea. But if I was in your case, I would compile the class with javac and check the results side by side.

Comment: Don't post a picture, it's pretty much useless.  Capture the output of javap and include that (formatted as code).  Are you sure your classfile format conforms to the JVM spec?

Answer (score 2):

Method `test` ends with a `return` instruction instead of an `ireturn` instruction. You can't use the former to return an int from a method; you have to use the latter.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I've overlooked the different kinds of returns.